# Text inside nested Row is not wrapping unless enclosing column is wrapped in Flexible widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The text inside my Text widget is not wrapping, even when wrapped in a Flexible widget. I found a workaround but it involves wrapping a Column widget inside a Flexible widget which I am not sure is best practice.

I have seen many similar answers online, but none for my exact problem. It is relevant that my text widget in question is nested inside the following hierachy Row -> Column -> Row

A rough idea of how this layout should look:
[image]
Here is the original code. When run the text overflows the screen rather than wrapping.

```dart
      Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text("top column"),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text("left row"),
                  Text(
                    "this is the text that needs to wrap, this is the text that needs to wrap",
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          ),
          Text("right side"),
        ],
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      );
```

Here is code that solves my problem, but it involves wrapping both the Text widget AND the outer Column widget in a Flexible widget:

```dart
      Row(
        children: [
          Flexible( // added Flexible widget, but doesn't seem correct.
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
              Text("top column"),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text("left row"),
                    Flexible( // added Flexible widget
                      child: Text(
                        "this is the text that needs to wrap, this is the text that needs to wrap",
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            ),
          ),
          Text("right side"),
        ],
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      );
```

Is there a better way to achieve this wrapping or is enclosing the Column in a Flexible widget a satisfactory approach?

Comment: The use of Flexible is really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is right, here's why :

You managed to the problem of the inner `Row` long text by wrap it into a `Flexible`,to prevent an overflow in the horizontal axis.This works perfectly if this is your whole tree,but this isn't the case.

Up on your widget tree there is no horizontal constraint limiting the width of children.`Column` wraps in the vertical axis, so the `children` of the upper-most `Row` one with fixed width (`Text("right side")`) and the other is unbounded one (`Column`).

When you wrapped the `Column` with `Flexible`, it made `children` bounded horizontally. Another approach would be to use a `Container`, but it is not the best one as it needs you to give the width before build.